# How do we say we are not using a template?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is the opposite of using a template for something?
For example:

> Should I use a template for this or am I free to follow my own format?

I would like to put it more eloquently/elegantly.
Thank you!

Comment: That's fine, GileBrt.

Comment: There is "freehand".

Comment: I might say, "...or create it from scratch?" More colloquially, I might use "...or just free-form it?"

Comment: Probably depends on what you are creating, as there are many uses for a template: whether writing an essay, article, or report; creating a web-page; writing software (source code); designing a wedding invitation, poster, ticket, flyer, or greeting card; publishing a book; making a PowerPoint presentation; specialised business-specific documents; and even more metaphorical uses such as planning an event where you might use a predefined structure.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I use a template for this or am I **on my own**?

**on one's own** (phrase)

> alone or unaided. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/on_one%27s_own)

> Commercially cut acrylic and plastic **template** shapes are also on
> the market...
> Looking back, I realize that I could have cut many of
> the shapes **on my own**. [Mary Mashuta; *Foolproof Machine
> Quilting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Foolproof_Machine_Quilting/OGdS6jH3d9kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22template%22%20or%20%20%22on%20my%20own%22&pg=PT21&printsec=frontcover)

> I am also indebted to Philip Goldberg, my coauthor on *Get Out of Your
> Own Way*, who developed the format that has served as such a great
> structure and **template** that I was able to forge ahead and write
> this one **on my own**. [Mark Goulston; *Get Out of Your Own Way at
> Work*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Get_Out_of_Your_Own_Way_at_Work_and_Help/67RbOyy8SA0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22template%22%20%22on%20my%20own%22&pg=PT256&printsec=frontcover)

A related, more elaborate idiom is

> Should I use a template for this or am I **left to my own devices**?

> **leave to one's own devices**
>
> In American English
> To allow to do as one wishes [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/leave-to-ones-own-devices)

> **leave someone to his or her own devices**
>
> To allow (someone) to do what he or she wants or is able to do without
> being controlled or helped by anyone else —often used as be **left to
> one's own devices** [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave%20someone%20to%20his%20or%20her%20own%20devices)]]

> When and how often these adjustments should take place is itself a
> matter for negotiation, but for illustrative purposes one such
> reorientation period is depicted on the **template**. Note, however,
> that at several intermediate points there are long periods when
> reviewers should be **left to their own devices**. [Ray Pawson;
> *Evidence-Based Policy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Evidence_Based_Policy/raAC7Ui-w7sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=template%20%22left%20to%20their%20own%20devices%22&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: All these phrases can, indeed, be used for the OP's purpose, **if** the context makes clear the contrast with using a template. They, however, do not by themselves, without such a context, carry the specific meaning of not using a template. One can, for example, ask 'Are you going to help me to write the report, or am I on my own?', when no template would be used either way. On the other hand, one can also ask 'Are you going to help me use the template, or will I be left to my own devices in using it?'

Comment: *Free-hand* can imply not using a template, but it words only for a physical template, which may not be the case in the OP's example. The OP provided an **example that specifically makes reference to a template**. Without that IMO only *templateless* would work if you don't mention a template. Unless you say "without a model" but that's not how I understand the question.